# Show confirm dialog in java

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, jbutton

Here's an ActionPerformed code for a logout button :

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();
    int option = jop.showConfirmDialog(null, "Voulez-vous vraiment vous déconnecter?", "Déconnexion", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
        this.dispose();
        Connexion connexion = new Connexion();
        connexion.setVisible(true);
    }           
}
```

Once I click right on the button, the application stops running
How can I handle this?

Here's the rest of code for that button

```
jButton5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/sinpec/deco.png"))); 
jButton5.setBorderPainted(false);
jButton5.setContentAreaFilled(false);
jButton5.setRolloverIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/sinpec/deco1.png"))); // NOI18N
jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
jPanel1.add(jButton5);
jButton5.setBounds(70, 0, 50, 50);
```

Comment: 1) The best formatting for blocks of code is had by selecting the code then clicking the `{}` button above the message posting/editing form. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not sure about `connexion`, but he is probably executing the code from a JFrame and so `this.dispose()` causes the app to close.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @Veluria  Good point.  I missed that first line..

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.dispose();
    Connexion connexion = new Connexion();
    connexion.setVisible(true);
```

Change the order?

```
    Connexion connexion = new Connexion();
    connexion.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
```

Comment: I even tried to put what's inside the if block on comment
but it doesn't solve the problem, the app still have the same problem once i click the logout button
So it seems like the problem is really coming from the showConfirmDialog .... I don't understand

Comment: Me either and since you have posted a MCVE/SSCE we can't help.